# Can I use the word 'encrypt' as hashing by cryptographic hash function in English?

Tags: encryption, hash

Now, I am reading [Identity and Data Security for Web Development: Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GP09AS6).
In this book, sometimes text like this appears.

> We then encrypt the password for the login attempt.
> (p40 Validating a Password Against a Hashed Value)

This chapter describes comparing user input passwords with the stored hash.
So the 'encrypt' means creating hash from raw data by a cryptographic hash function in the text I think.

I want to know can I use both the word 'encrypt' and 'hash' for action as both creating hash that can't be decrypted from. Or can I use only 'encrypt' when encrypted value can be decrypted?

Comment: This might be better for [english.se], but I would say _strictly_ hashing isn't encryption as it's irreversible.

Comment: Hash and encrypt aren't interchangeable and have different meanings. Most likely the book is wrong and the phrase should be `We then hash the password for the login attempt`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand feelilngs now.

Comment: Please don't intermix those two words, a lot of confusion about safe password storage comes from mixing up encryption and hashing in internet articles! Encryption is always two-way and decryptable, hashing is always one-way and not recoverable.